# Getting AngularUI Bootstrap datepicker to recognize YYYYMMDD format?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have legacy birth date data in the format of `YYYYMMDD` (*20151022*). Angular and the ui-bootstrap datepicker obviously don't like this format. Also, our new UI requirements are to display the format as `MMM, d YYYY` (*Oct, 22 2015*). I'm not seeing a way to enforce a non-standard date format (for data, not for display) in the documentation. Is this not supported or am I just overlooking it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your datepicker is bound to a variable - `ng-model="date"`. Then simply `$watch` this variable and do the nessecary formatting when a string is assigned to it :

```js
$scope.date = ''; 

$scope.$watch('date', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (typeof newValue == 'string') {
      var tempDate = new Date(
          newValue.substr(4,2)+'-'+
          newValue.substr(6,2)+'-'+
          newValue.substr(0,4)
       );
       $scope.date = !isNaN(tempDate.getTime()) ? tempDate : new Date();
    }
})
```

This will return a valid date object if you have assigned a string to `date` on the format `yyyymmdd`; if something has gone wrong `date` will be set to today.

```js
$scope.date = '20151022'; //set the datepicker to 10-22-2015
$scope.date = new Date('01-01-1900') //etc works as usual
```

In order to use a display format on the form `Oct, 22 2015` you are almost right, it should just be lowercase `y`'s :

```js
uib-datepicker-popup="MMM, d yyyy"
```

the above in a plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/ne60bBaTuca7wajTHP9w?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks @davidkonrad. This helps to get me closer, however I need to send the data back to the server in the legacy `YYYYMMDD` format.